How to solve this MAUI dependencies hell
I have a MAUI app which has these packages:

I have updated all packages so there is nothing else to update.
However, after some short time, the dependency Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility is replaced by an older version, resulting this:

This is really a headache. It seems other updated package need 8.0.6 version but I cannot figure out which one. How can I solve this?
I cannot even uninstall Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility neither Microsoft.Maui.Controls to start over.
EDIT: This is the current project file. I have manually removed both reference also pero is still appearing in the solution packages node:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFrameworks>net8.0-ios;net8.0-android</TargetFrameworks>
        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <RootNamespace>TimeApp</RootNamespace>
        <UseMaui>true</UseMaui>
        <SingleProject>true</SingleProject>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>

        <!-- Display name -->
        <ApplicationTitle>My Title</ApplicationTitle>

        <!-- App Identifier -->
        <ApplicationId>com.desytec.dattendance</ApplicationId>
        <ApplicationIdGuid>2DD1655E-4002-4212-B68D-5235178B5FC3</ApplicationIdGuid>

        <!-- Versions -->
        <ApplicationDisplayVersion>1.0</ApplicationDisplayVersion>
        <ApplicationVersion>1</ApplicationVersion>

        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'ios'">11.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'maccatalyst'">14.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'android'">31.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'windows'">10.0.17763.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
        <TargetPlatformMinVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'windows'">10.0.17763.0</TargetPlatformMinVersion>
        <Platforms>AnyCPU;x64</Platforms>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <!-- App Icon -->
        <MauiIcon Include="Resources\AppIcon\appicon.svg" Color="White" />

        <!-- Splash Screen -->
        <MauiSplashScreen Include="Resources\Splash\splash.svg" Color="White" BaseSize="128,128" />

        <!-- Images -->
        <MauiImage Include="Resources\Images\*" />
        <MauiImage Update="Resources\Images\dotnet_bot.svg" BaseSize="168,208" />

        <!-- Custom Fonts -->
        <MauiFont Include="Resources\Fonts\*" />

        <!-- Raw Assets (also remove the "Resources\Raw" prefix) -->
        <MauiAsset Include="Resources\Raw\**" LogicalName="%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <None Remove="appsettings.json" />
      <None Remove="Resources\Fonts\Roboto-Regular.ttf" />
      <None Remove="Resources\Images\lock.png" />
      <None Remove="Resources\Images\login_logo.png" />
      <None Remove="Resources\Images\profile.svg" />
      <None Remove="Resources\Images\user.png" />
      <None Remove="Resources\Raw\check_animated.json" />
      <None Remove="Resources\Raw\failed_animated.json" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <EmbeddedResource Include="appsettings.json" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <PackageReference Include="CommunityToolkit.Maui" Version="9.0.3" />
      <PackageReference Include="CommunityToolkit.MVVM" Version="8.2.2" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite" Version="8.0.8" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder" Version="8.0.2" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" Version="8.0.0" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Maps" Version="8.0.82" />
      <PackageReference Include="SimpleToolkit.Core" Version="5.1.2" />
      <PackageReference Include="SkiaSharp.Extended" Version="2.0.0" />
      <PackageReference Include="SkiaSharp.Extended.UI.Maui" Version="2.0.0" />
      <PackageReference Include="SkiaSharp.Views.Maui.Controls" Version="3.0.0-preview.1.8" />
      <PackageReference Include="UraniumUI" Version="2.9.1" />
      <PackageReference Include="UraniumUI.Material" Version="2.9.1" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <Compile Update="Properties\Resources.Designer.cs">
        <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
        <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
        <DependentUpon>Resources.resx</DependentUpon>
      </Compile>
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <EmbeddedResource Update="Properties\Resources.resx">
        <Generator>ResXFileCodeGenerator</Generator>
        <LastGenOutput>Resources.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
      </EmbeddedResource>
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <MauiXaml Update="Controls\AttendanceControl.xaml">
        <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
      </MauiXaml>
      <MauiXaml Update="Controls\FooterControl.xaml">
        <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
      </MauiXaml>
      <MauiXaml Update="Controls\HeaderControl.xaml">
        <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
      </MauiXaml>
      <MauiXaml Update="Controls\ShiftControl.xaml">
        <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
      </MauiXaml>
      <MauiXaml Update="Controls\Wizard\Steps\SetupWizardStep1View.xaml">
        <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
      </MauiXaml>
      <MauiXaml Update="Controls\Wizard\Steps\SetupWizardStep2View.xaml">
        <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
      </MauiXaml>
      <MauiXaml Update="Controls\Wizard\Steps\SetupWizardStep3View.xaml">
        <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
      </MauiXaml>
      <MauiXaml Update="Controls\Wizard\Steps\SetupWizardWelcomeView.xaml">
        <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
      </MauiXaml>
      <MauiXaml Update="Controls\Wizard\WizardStepsControl.xaml">
        <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
      </MauiXaml>
      <MauiXaml Update="Views\EnrolamientoPage.xaml">
        <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
      </MauiXaml>
      <MauiXaml Update="Views\LoadingPage.xaml">
        <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
      </MauiXaml>
      <MauiXaml Update="Views\LoginPage.xaml">
        <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
      </MauiXaml>
    </ItemGroup>

    <PropertyGroup Label="MauiAppAccelerator">
        <wizardVersion>v1.3.1</wizardVersion>
        <projectType>MVVMToolkit</projectType>
        <framework>Flyout</framework>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(TargetFramework)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|net7.0-maccatalyst|AnyCPU'">
      <ApplicationId>com.company.product</ApplicationId>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(TargetFramework)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|net8.0-ios|AnyCPU'">
      <ApplicationId>com.company.product/ApplicationId>
      <ApplicationDisplayVersion>1.0.10</ApplicationDisplayVersion>
      <ApplicationTitle>My Title</ApplicationTitle>
      <MtouchLink>None</MtouchLink>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(TargetFramework)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|net8.0-android|AnyCPU'">
      <ApplicationId>com.company.product</ApplicationId>
      <ApplicationDisplayVersion>1.0.10</ApplicationDisplayVersion>
      <ApplicationTitle>My Title</ApplicationTitle>
      <AndroidUseAapt2>True</AndroidUseAapt2>
      <AndroidCreatePackagePerAbi>False</AndroidCreatePackagePerAbi>
      <AndroidPackageFormat>apk</AndroidPackageFormat>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(TargetFramework)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|net7.0-maccatalyst|x64'">
      <ApplicationId>com.company.product</ApplicationId>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(TargetFramework)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|net8.0-ios|x64'">
      <ApplicationId>com.company.product</ApplicationId>
      <ApplicationDisplayVersion>1.0.10</ApplicationDisplayVersion>
      <ApplicationTitle>My Title</ApplicationTitle>
      <MtouchLink>None</MtouchLink>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(TargetFramework)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|net8.0-android|x64'">
      <ApplicationId>com.company.product</ApplicationId>
      <ApplicationDisplayVersion>1.0.10</ApplicationDisplayVersion>
      <ApplicationTitle>My Title</ApplicationTitle>
      <AndroidUseAapt2>True</AndroidUseAapt2>
      <AndroidCreatePackagePerAbi>False</AndroidCreatePackagePerAbi>
      <AndroidPackageFormat>apk</AndroidPackageFormat>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(TargetFramework)|$(Platform)'=='Release|net7.0-maccatalyst|AnyCPU'">
      <ApplicationId>com.company.product</ApplicationId>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(TargetFramework)|$(Platform)'=='Release|net8.0-ios|AnyCPU'">
      <ApplicationId>com.company.product</ApplicationId>
      <ApplicationDisplayVersion>1.0.10</ApplicationDisplayVersion>
      <ApplicationTitle>My Title</ApplicationTitle>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(TargetFramework)|$(Platform)'=='Release|net8.0-android|AnyCPU'">
      <ApplicationId>com.company.product</ApplicationId>
      <ApplicationDisplayVersion>1.0.10</ApplicationDisplayVersion>
      <AndroidPackageFormat>apk</AndroidPackageFormat>
      <ApplicationTitle>My Title</ApplicationTitle>
      <AndroidUseAapt2>True</AndroidUseAapt2>
      <AndroidCreatePackagePerAbi>False</AndroidCreatePackagePerAbi>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(TargetFramework)|$(Platform)'=='Release|net7.0-maccatalyst|x64'">
      <ApplicationId>com.company.product</ApplicationId>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(TargetFramework)|$(Platform)'=='Release|net8.0-ios|x64'">
      <ApplicationId>com.company.product</ApplicationId>
      <ApplicationDisplayVersion>1.0.10</ApplicationDisplayVersion>
      <ApplicationTitle>My Title</ApplicationTitle>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(TargetFramework)|$(Platform)'=='Release|net8.0-android|x64'">
      <ApplicationId>com.company.product</ApplicationId>
      <ApplicationDisplayVersion>1.0.10</ApplicationDisplayVersion>
      <AndroidPackageFormat>apk</AndroidPackageFormat>
      <ApplicationTitle>My Title</ApplicationTitle>
      <AndroidUseAapt2>True</AndroidUseAapt2>
      <AndroidCreatePackagePerAbi>False</AndroidCreatePackagePerAbi>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)'=='net8.0-ios'">
      <CodesignKey>Apple Development: My Name (Certain code)</CodesignKey>
      <CodesignProvision>VS: com.company.product Development</CodesignProvision>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ProjectExtensions><VisualStudio><UserProperties XamarinHotReloadDebuggerTimeoutExceptionDAttendanceHideInfoBar="True" /></VisualStudio></ProjectExtensions>

</Project>


What does your csproj look like?

@GeraldVersluis I have edited the question to show the project file content.

Try adding a reference to Microsoft.Maui.Controls with version 8.0.82 (latest at the time of writing) directly and the Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility with the same version should you need it.

I usually create new MAUI project and start to add nuget packages  to it
always after adding new one, I clean solution and rebuild

I can't reproduce your problem. I copied the package references to a new maui project's csproj file. And there is no problem. The Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility and the Microsoft.Maui.Controls are both 8.0.72 version.
